# AJV schema validation for array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajv

I am trying to validate array of objects using AJV schema validation. Below is the sample code

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var schemaValidator = Ajv();

var innerSchema = {
"type" : "object",
"properties" : {
    "c" :  {
        "type" : "string"
    },
    "d" : {
        "type" : "number"
    }
},
"required" : ["c"]
}

var innerArraySchema = {
"type": "array",
"items" : {
    "#ref": innerSchema
}
}

var schema = {
"type" : "object",
"properties" : {
    "a" :  {
        "type" : "string"
    },
    "b" : {
        "type" : "string"
    },
    "obj" : innerArraySchema
},
"required" : ["a"]
}

var testSchemaValidator = schemaValidator.compile(schema);

var data = {"a": "123","b" : "abc", "obj" : [{
"d" : "ankit"
}]}


var valid = testSchemaValidator(data);

console.log(valid);

if(!valid) {
    console.log(testSchemaValidator.errors);
}
```

Is there something that I am missing here. I would not like to add the properties object inside the array definition itself.

Comment: Resolved the issue by eliminating ref keyword.

var innerArraySchema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items" : innerSchema
}

Answer (score 45):

Resolved the issue by using:

```
var innerArraySchema = {
"type": "array",
"items" : innerSchema
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `$ref` not `#ref`.

Also note that you can load a schema by ID:

```
var innerArraySchema = {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    $ref: 'https://www.example.com/my-schema.schema.json',
  },
  "items" : innerSchema
}
```

Note that using a schema ID (URL) in this way will NOT cause the schema to be imported automatically; you will need to use `Ajv.getSchema()` or `Ajv.addSchema()` to load the schema, too.

There's more info in the [docs on combining schemas.](https://ajv.js.org/guide/combining-schemas.html)