# How to describe and validate an array of objects with cuid as key and value as an object with specific properties

Tags: javascript, json, validation, schema, ajv

I have a unique data that I am attempting to validate:

```
{
            "name": "Some random name",
            "blocks": [
                {"cj5458hyl0001zss42td3waww": {
                    "quantity": 9,
                    "rate": 356.77,
                    "dId": "ewdwe4434"
                }},
                {"cj5458hyl0001zss42td3wawu": {
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "rate": 356.77,
                    "dId": "3434ewdwe4434"
                }}]
}
```

Here is the composition that I have right now (***invalid and incorrect***):

```
const subSchema = {
    "type": ["string"],
    "pattern": "/^c[^\s-]{8,}$/",
    "properties": {
        "quantity": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "rate": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "dId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": ["quantity", "rate", "dId"]
};

const schema = {
    "type": ["object"],
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "blocks": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": subSchema,
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "minItems": 1
        }
    },
    "required": ["name", "blocks"]
};
```

and how I am validating it (for context):

```
const { BadRequestError } = require("restify");
const ajv = require("ajv");
var schemaValidator = ajv();

const validateRoomTypePostRequest = (req, res, next) => {

    if (req.body && req.body.data){
        const blockReq = Object.assign({}, req.body.data);
        const testSchemaValidator = schemaValidator.compile(schema);
        const valid = testSchemaValidator(blockReq);
        if (!valid) {
            const messages = testSchemaValidator.errors.map(e => {
                return e.message;
            });
            return next(new BadRequestError(JSON.stringify(messages)));
        }
        return next();
    }
    else {
        return next(new BadRequestError("Invalid or non-existent request body"));
    }
};
```

Here is what I have referenced so far:

1) [AJV schema validation for array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133426/ajv-schema-validation-for-array-of-objects)

2) https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/KEYWORDS.md

3) https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html

Additional information:

1) Using **Node 8.1.3**

2) *AJV* version **5.2**

I know that I need to use an array of items to describe the object. However the object contains a unique cuid as a key and the value as a an object. I would like to understand how to describe this data using such a schema that validates the nested properties and the cuid. I welcome feedback on how to best approach this data. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I did some soul searching and realized that all I had to do was leverage the `patternProperties`keyword, specific to strings.

```
{
    "blockType": {
        "additionalProperties": false,
            "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                         "type": "string"
                    },
                    "blocks": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "patternProperties": {
                            "^[a-z][a-z0-9\\-]*$": {
                                "type": ["object"],
                                "properties": {
                                    "rate": {
                                        "type": ["integer"]
                                    },
                                    "quantity": {
                                        "type": ["integer"]
                                    },
                                    "dId": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                            "additionalProperties": false,
                            "required": ["dId", "quantity", "rate"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    "required": ["name", "blocks"]
    }
}
```

I could improve the regex for validating the cuid.